# Does "old" rsh exist in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, remote-access

I wanted to try out `rsh` (or `rshell`?) - the old, insecure way of logging in remotely.

On my Ubuntu 11.04, it turns out an `rsh` command exists:

```
$ which rsh
/usr/bin/rsh
```

... however, it turns out it is a mere symlink for `ssh`:

```
$ ls -la `which rsh`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 2011-03-25 16:07 /usr/bin/rsh -> /etc/alternatives/rsh

$ ls -la $(readlink -f `which rsh`)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 391580 2011-04-02 12:16 /usr/bin/ssh
```

Does this "old" `rsh` exist in Ubuntu repositories - and if so, how do I install it? Also, is `rsh` also split in client and server packages - and if so, which packages are those?

Comment: The package `rsh-client` looks promising

Comment: Many thanks, @GeraldSchneider - indeed, just installed it, and now `rsh` is not ssh anymore; and there is a `rsh-server` package too... Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the package `rsh-client`.

Installing it should change the symlink to the newly installed rsh file, if not you can change it using `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Check also the answer by [@Oli](http://askubuntu.com/a/338319/6808) for the alternative "redone" implementation of `rsh`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two versions. Classic `rsh-{server,client}` and the newer `rsh-redone-{server,client}` (which still has no encryption but has support for things like IPv6).

```
$ apt-cache show ^rsh  # output is trimmed

Package: rsh-server
Description-en: server program for remote shell connections
 This package contains rexecd, rlogind and rshd.

Package: rsh-client
Description-en: client programs for remote shell connections
 This package contains rsh, rcp and rlogin.

Package: rsh-redone-client
Description-en: Reimplementation of rsh and rlogin
 Rsh-redone is a reimplementation of the remote shell clients and servers.
 It is written from the ground up to avoid the bugs found in the standard
 clients and servers. It also fully supports IPv6.
 .
 This package provides rsh and rlogin.

Package: rsh-redone-server
Description-en: Reimplementation of rshd and rlogind
 Rsh-redone is a reimplementation of the remote shell clients and servers.
 It is written from the ground up to avoid the bugs found in the standard
 clients and servers. It also fully supports IPv6.
 .
 This package provides rshd and rlogind.
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @Oli - would never have guessed there are two implementations of `rsh`; great to know this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install the following packages:

rsh-client - client programs for remote shell connections

rsh-server - server program for remote shell connections

Thomas

Comment: Many thanks for that \@tpf - @GeraldSchneider was faster in this case; cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the packages `rsh-redone-client` and `rsh-redone-server`.

They do the job.